# What is wrong with MIPS Fibonacci Recursion?

Tags: assembly, mips

I am working in converting a fibonacci function written in C to MIPS. My MIPS code is currently not working and I can not identify the issue. I am new to assembly and I hope you can help me identifying the main problem in my MIPS code. Look at my function fibonacci under my MIPS code. When I compile my MIPS code I get the following error : "Can't expand stack segment by 24 bytes to 5242888 bytes.

I have a C code as following:

```or-tag-here
int fib(int n) {
    if (n == 0) {
        return 0;
    } else if (n == 1) 
    {
        return 1;
    }
    return fib(n-1) + fib(n-2);}
```

I have my MIPS as following:

```
        .text
            .globl main
    main:


 subu $sp,$sp,32         # Stack frame is 32 bytes long
        sw $ra,20($sp)          # Save return address
        sw $fp,16($sp)          # Save old frame pointer
        addiu $fp,$sp,28        # Set up frame pointer

        li $a0,10               # Put argument (10) in $a0
        jal fibonacci                # Call fibonacci function
        move $t0,$v0            # Move fact result to $t0 (temporary)
        la $a0,$LC              # Put format string in $a0
        li $v0, 4               # System call code for print_str
        syscall                 # Make system call
        move $a0, $t0           # Move $t0 fibonacci result to $a0 (argument)
        li $v0, 1               # System call code for print_int
        syscall                 # Make system call
        #jal printf              # Call the print function

        lw $ra,20($sp)          # Restore return address
        lw $fp,16($sp)          # Restore frame pointer
        addiu $sp,$sp,32        # Pop stack frame
        jr $ra                  # Return to caller

        .rdata
$LC:
        .ascii "The fibonacci of 10 is "

    .text
fibonacci:
        subu $sp,$sp,32         # Stack framee is 32 bytes long
        sw $ra,20($sp)          # Save return address
        sw $fp,16($sp)          # Save frame pointer
        addiu $fp,$sp,28        # Set up frame pointer
        sw $a0,0($fp)           # Save argument (n)
        sw $a1,4($fp)

        lw $v0,0($fp)           # Load n
        li $v0,1                # Return 1

        # a0 = n
        # v0 = return_value 

        move $s0, $a0           #put n in $s0
        bne $s0, $0, not_zero   # if n doesn't equal to zero go to else if
        add $v0, $0, 0          # set return value to zero 
        j exit                  #go to exit

not_zero:
        li    $t0, 1                # assigning t0 to 1
        bne   $s0, $t0, test_two    # if no equal to one go to the else
        add   $v0, $0, 1            # set return value to one
        j exit                      # go to exit

test_two:

        addi $a0, $s0, -1   # assign $a0 = n -1
        jal fibonacci
        move $s1, $v0

        addi  $a0, $s0, -1  # assign $a0 = n -1
        jal fibonacci
        add   $v0, $s1, $v0 # Add f_(n-1) + f_(n-2)
        j exit

exit:                           # Result is in $v0
        lw $ra, 20($sp)         # Restore $ra
        lw $fp, 16($sp)         # Restore $fp
        addiu $sp, $sp, 32      # Pop stack
        jr $ra                  # Return to caller
```

Comment: 1) You can't get such error while **compiling** the source (or actually you *can*, but that means you have found a bug in the assembler, but not in this case). 2) spim/mars simulators family of tools have built-in debugger, so you can go much further then just helplessly executing the code, and watching how it reports error. Leaving that out to the stackoverflow audience is sort of rude, debugging is time consuming task, and it is expected from the OP to do his own part first, describing in question what he found during debugging. Also helps to identify deficiencies in your logic and knowledge

Comment: 3) that message contains big hint about what is wrong about the code, even without checking single line of it. It says that the simulator failed to enlarge the "stack" area of simulated memory from 5MiB size to +24 more bytes. Now if you can't tell that such simple code using 5MiB of stack memory for `fib(10)` is wrong, then you have no idea how much 5MiB is. So obviously the recursion goes much deeper than expected, filling up stack fully. So either you lose your code-flow control after some call, or your termination conditions are wrong, or your stack restoration+exit is wrong. Or all of it.

Comment: 4) even if your code would output correct value after running it, it is very wrong to conclude on your side, that it is correct, and mark it "done". That's not how assembly programming works, you can often receive correct result by accident, while the code still contains subtle bugs. So even with correct output received you should still do one final round of single-stepping-debugging over each instruction, reasoning about it exact effect and purpose, and your original intent, if everything works as it was supposed and nothing else is being affected or some other memory overwritten, etc..

Comment: @Ped7g why is it rude to leave out to the stack overflow audience? I spent hours and hours trying to understand the issue or error. I ask for help in this forum perhaps someone has a similar issue and knows how to fix it.

Comment: Because you spend them ineffectively, and you don't provide in the question vital "basic" information, which can be found out by yourself in couple of hours, if you would use debugger to single-step over instructions and go in the recursion at least few levels deep (like doing f(10), f(9) and f(8) may be easily enough for you to see if some basic discrepancy is forming up against your original plans, like for example f(10) calls f(10) self, etc). "similar issue" = answer then is the "3)" point in my comments, that's complete answer. Now use debugger or watch your source to figure out details.

Comment: Now I did read your source, and you don't preserve `s0` and `s1` between calls. So your assumption `addi  $a0, $s0, -1  # assign $a0 = n -1` fails, you will get different value in some calls. Also I didn't understand your `sp` + `fp` adjustments logic (why 32+28 and why displacements 20, 16, 0, 4 ... if you would check actual final addresses used, you would found out you are sort of zig-zagging all over memory (in tens of bytes only, nothing major, but it irks me as seasoned developer, because it almost feels like you are not in full control understanding the stack concept up to 100%)).

Comment: And that `s0` having "wrong value" inside (I **guess** it would look like this: `f(3)` call after calling `f(2)` (which will work calling `f(1)` and `f(0)`) will do `f(-1)` instead of `f(1)` and from there it will do `f(-i)` calls infinitely, but check in debugger yourself) - is something you would clearly notice, after stepping over ~160 instructions, which is well within human possibilities. Also it may sometimes give you idea how to simplify your code (to have less to debug), and also it may gave you idea about simpler test cases (like trying first `f(0)` and `f(1)`, then `f(2)`, etc..).

Comment: And finally you can use breakpoints also, so if you are particularly happy about some block of code (after stepping through it few times and having clear idea how it works and what to check before entering it to know what will be result), you can "step" over it by running till next breakpoint, saving you some stepping. (please also notice I didn't downvote you as low effort or unclear, while it technically **is**, but I accept you did your best up to your skills, so these my comments are attacking your lack of skill, in my try to push you up toward required level, not to put you down).