# MIPS loop factorial error (no recursion needed)

Tags: assembly, mips, mips32

I am having an issue with this code. This is a program that is supposed to calculate the factorial of a number using the functions fact and L1, these were provided by my instructor and I needed to make the main function in order for it to work.

I documented as much as I could without making it cluttered.I do not really need recursion for this code as it is not specified and we have not covered that topic yet.
Whenever I execute this code on qtspim I get  message saying that

> can't expand stack segment by 8 bytes to 1048576 bytes. Use-lstack# with# > 1048576

after this qtspim stops working for a second.

**note**: I cannot change the fact and L1 functions.

What is wrong here?
Please explain and thanks.

```
fact:
slti $t0, $a0, 1        # test for n < 1
beq $t0, $zero, L1      # if n >= 1, go to L1
li  $v0, 1              # return 1
jr  $ra                 # return to instruction after jal

L1: 
addi    $sp, $sp, -8    # adjust stack for 2 items
sw  $ra, 4($sp) # save the return address
sw  $a0, 0($sp) # save the argument n

addi    $a0, $a0, -1    # n >= 1; argument gets (n – 1)
jal fact        # call fact with (n – 1)

lw  $a0, 0($sp) # return from jal: restore argument n
lw  $ra, 4($sp) # restore the return address
addi    $sp, $sp, 8 # adjust stack pointer to pop 2 items

mul $v0, $a0, $v0   # return n * fact (n – 1)

jr  $ra     # return to the caller

.text
main: 

la $a0, greet       # display greetings
li $v0, 3 
syscall         # syscall on print greetings

dri:    
la $a0, enter       # display message that asks reader 
li $v0, 3 
syscall         # system call on print question

li $v0, 6       # value of n is read
syscall         # system call

slt $t0, $v0, $zero     # condition of program end
bne $t0, $zero, close   # if user types a number less than zero it closes           
move $s0, $v0       # save value of n move $a0, $v0 # place value of n in $a0
jal fact        # call fact function
move $s1, $v0       # fact value is saved
move $a0, $s0       # result is displayed
li $v0, 1       # value of n is printed
syscall         # system call

la $a0, answer      # displays the textual portion of the answers
li $v0, 3               
syscall         # system call
move $a0, $s1       # print factorial
li $v0, 1 
syscall         # system call
la $a0, newline     # display newline
li $v0, 3 
syscall         # system call
j dri           # process is repeated until user decides

close: 
la $a0, bye     # farewell message
li $v0, 3 
syscall         # system call
li $v0, 10      # exit from the program 
syscall
.data
greet: .asciiz "Welcome to the factorial tester!\n"
enter: .asciiz "Enter a value for n (or a negative value to exit): "
answer: .asciiz "! is "
newline: .asciiz "\n"
bye: .asciiz "Come back soon!\n"

# end fact.s
```

Comment: Why do you even execute machine code without debugging it first? If you would get correct answer on screen, what would you do, close it as "done"? :D ... to check correctness of assembly code you have to single-step over it several times in debugger, and reason about every instruction, and every state, if it is really what you wanted, and does exactly only what you wanted, and do that for several different inputs. In assembly you can often get correct on-screen output even when the code has fundamental problems, which will appear for some other inputs, so testing by executing is useless.

Comment: Anyway, this comment should be general pointer for you what is wrong (many options): https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48575276/what-is-wrong-with-mips-fibonacci-recursion?noredirect=1#comment84152639_48575276 ... anyway, by quick look into your source, either you messed formatting, or you don't set `a0` before calling `fact` subroutine (which *is* recursive, but looks correct to me on first read). (the needed `move` looks to ended as comment of previous line)